# Unit vectors starting with $4/5$.

Tags: linear-programming

Find a unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has first component 4/5. Can we describe all such vectors?

Comment: Do you know what a unit vector is? Do you know at least one example  of a unit vector that is not a column of the identity matrix? Then this should be easy.

Answer (score 2):

Let the unit vector be $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{4}{5}\\y\\z\\ \end{pmatrix}$.
As the magnitude of an unit vector is $1$, we get $$\frac{16}{25} + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \implies y^2 + z^2 = \left ( \frac{3}{5}\right ) ^ {2}$$
Hence all the required vectors are of the form $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{4}{5}\\y\\z\\ \end{pmatrix}$ where $(y, z)$ lie on a circle of radius $\frac{3}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

suppose ($4/5$  $x$  $y$) is all unit vectors starting with $4/5$ for choises of $x$ and $y$. Then solve the equation $16/25+x^2+y^2=1$ to get the value of x and y. These will be the full collection.

Answer (score 0):

It is the intersection of two elements:

- the unit sphere
- the plane $x = \frac{4}{5}$

This should be a circle parallel to plane $yOz$ and has a radius
$$ r = \sqrt{1-x^2} = \frac{3}{5} $$
The center of the circle is $(x, 0, 0)$